# Group time intervals array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that generates an array of a time interval. All right, it works well, it gets 3 points, the start time, end and the time in minutes to generate the array

```
  function GeraHorario(inicio,fim,tempoConsulta)
  {
    var consultas = Math.floor(60/tempoConsulta);
    for (var i = 0; i <= consultas; i++) {
      $scope.consultasHora.push(i)
    }
    var agenda = []
    var data = new Date(2016, 0, 1, inicio, 0, 0, 0)
    var horainicial = inicio
    while (data.getDate() == 1) {
      if(data.getHours() < fim)
      {
          var horario = data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
          data.setMinutes(data.getMinutes()+tempoConsulta);
          //agenda.push(horario.replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1'));
          var d1 = horario.replace(/(.*)\D\d+/, '$1');
          agenda.push(d1.replace(/:/g,''));
      }else{break}
    }
    console.log(agenda)
    return agenda
  }
```

It generates this array:

```
["0900", "0911", "0922", "0933", "0944", "0955", "1000", "1006", "1017", "1028", "1039", "1050", "1100", "1101", "1112", "1123", "1134", "1145", "1156", "1200", "1207", "1218", "1229", "1240", "1251", "1300", "1302", "1313", "1324", "1335", "1346", "1357", "1400", "1408", "1419", "1430", "1441", "1452", "1500", "1503", "1514", "1525", "1536", "1547", "1558", "1600", "1609", "1620", "1631", "1642", "1653", "1700", "1704", "1715", "1726", "1737", "1748", "1759", "1800", "1810", "1821", "1832", "1843", "1854", "1900"]
```

**What I need is to divide the array of values, for example from 0900 until 1000.
That in fact this is 0900 09:00 10:00 however I remove the:. What I need is to group these intervals schedules, type 9 to 10, 10 to 11 and so on. Can anyone help?**

```
["0900", "0911", "0922", "0933", "0944", "0955"]

["1000", "1006", "1017", "1028", "1039", "1050"]
```

Comment: Maybe `% 1000` (module)?

Comment: Iterate through the array, read the first two characters (either as a string or int, whichever you prefer) and assign them to a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the original array into a map or another array.

```
var result = agenda.reduce(function( map, hourStr ) {
    var hour = hourStr.charAt(0) + hourStr.charAt(1);
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(hour)) map[hour] = [];
    map[hour].push(hourStr);
    return map;
}, {});
```

2-dimensional array version:

```
var result = agenda.sort().reduce(function( map, hourStr ) {
        var hour = hourStr.charAt(0) + hourStr.charAt(1);
        if (!map.indices.hasOwnProperty(hour)) {
            map.indices[hour] = map.ary.length;
            map.ary.push([]);
        }
        map.ary[map.indices[hour]].push(hourStr);
        return map;     
    }, {
        'indices' : {},
        'ary' : []
    }).ary;
```

Comment: Its sort it in ascending order?

Comment: The inner arrays will contain the hours in the order they were in in the original array, so they should be sorted. The result map though, is an object in this version, so its keys are unsorted.

Comment: It is because the first value has become the last when I make the map. only the first one that went to the final, the rest is in order

Comment: `Object {10: Array[6], 11: Array[6], 12: Array[6], 13: Array[6], 14: Array[6], 15: Array[6], 16: Array[6], 17: Array[6], 18: Array[6], 09: Array[6]}`

Comment: You can't sort an object, but when using the map, you can easily sort the keys: `Object.keys(result).sort().forEach(function( key ) {});` You could always rewrite the reduction to use an array instead fo a map, it just needs a bit more code to 'remember' at which index each hour array is.

Comment: Added a version that will create a 2d array. The first index will contain the array with the ealiest hours.

Answer (score 0):

here is a non string approach:

```
var groups = {};
for(var index in agenda){
  var time = times[index];
  var groupId = Math.floor(parseInt(time) / 100);
  if(!groups[groupId]) groups[groupId] = [];
  groups[groupId].push(time);
}
```